# How to apply inverted color with ColorMatrix to Android Camera2 API video?

Tags: android, matrix, colors, android-camera2

Is it possible to apply inverted colors to Android Camera2 API video?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not easily.

The most efficient way to do this would be to pipe the camera data to the GPU, run a fragment shader there to invert colors, and then pipe the output to a video encoder.

That's quite a bit of boilerplate, unfortunately:

- Create and configure a MediaCodec or MediaRecorder (probably the former, in which case you also need a MediaMuxer to write a video file if that's what you want in the end)
- Create an EGL or Vulkan context, use the Surface from the MediaCodec/Recorder as an destination Image to draw to.  Create a SurfaceTexture to render the camera output into.
- Set up the camera using the SurfaceTexture from GL/Vulkan.
- Write GL/Vulkan code to render a quad with the texture from Camera, and a fragment shader to invert colors
- When desired, start up the MediaCodec/Recorder, send frames from Camera to the SurfaceTexture, and save the file to disk.

On the plus side, once you have all this, doing a lot of other effects is pretty easy.